# c++ Dynamic Allocation of 2D Array Class

Tags: c++, arrays

Very new beginner here and I'm at the end of my rope with this assignment and would really appreciate any help :). Apologies in advance for the length.

I'm having some trouble with retrieving and setting values for my dynamically allocated 2D array. I have a class, defined below, that should construct a 2D array, at which point I need the option to set a value to a given point in the array and also to retrieve a value at a given point.

I ran the debugger, and got as far as to figure out that I have a segmentation fault when the setValue function runs. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? As a beginner, the easier terms the better :). Thank you kindly in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class array2D
{
    protected:
        int xRes;
        int yRes;
        float ** xtable;

    public:
        array2D (int xResolution, int yResolution);
        ~array2D() {}
        void getSize(int &xResolution, int &yResolution);
        void setValue(int x,int y,float val);
        float getValue(int x,int y);
};


array2D::array2D(int xResolution, int yResolution)
{
    xRes=xResolution;
    yRes=yResolution;

    float ** xtable = new float*[yResolution];

    for(int i=0;i < yResolution;i++)
    {
        xtable[i] = new float[xResolution];
    }

    for(int i=0;i < yRes;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j < xRes;j++)
        {
            xtable[i][j]=45;
        }
    }
}

void array2D::getSize(int &xResolution, int &yResolution)
{
    xResolution=xRes;
    yResolution=yRes;
    cout << "Size of Array: " << xResolution << ", " << yResolution << endl;
}

void array2D::setValue(int x,int y,float val)
{
    xtable[x][y] = val;
}

float array2D::getValue(int x,int y)
{
    return xtable[x][y];
}

int main()
{
    array2D *a = new array2D(320,240);
    int xRes, yRes;
    a->getSize(xRes,yRes);
    for(int i=0;i < yRes;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j < xRes;j++)
        {
            a->setValue(i,j,100.0);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i < yRes;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j < xRes;j++)
        {
            cout << a->getValue(i,j) << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    delete[] a;
}
```

Comment: I applaud all the details with your first post.

Comment: Why are you not using `std::vector`?

Comment: Unfortunately std::vector is not something we've covered the use of yet, so it's somewhat 'forbidden' to use for this project :)

Comment: Why are you not incrementing the indices of `xTable` inside the class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
float ** xtable = new float*[yResolution];
```

creates a function local variable. The member variable of the class still remains uninitialized. That's not what you want. To allocate memory and assign it to the member variable, remove the type specifier from that line. Just use:

```
xtable = new float*[yResolution];
```

Also, you need to switch the use of `yResolution` and `xResolution` in those lines. Otherwise, `getValue` and `setValue` will be using the indices incorrectly.

Swap the use of `xResolution` and `yResolution` in the following lines so that you use:

```
float ** xtable = new float*[xResolution];
for(int i=0;i < xResolution;i++)
{
    xtable[i] = new float[yResolution];
}
```

Swap the use of `xRes` and `yRes` in the following lines so that you use:

```
for(int i=0;i < xRes;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j < yRes;j++)
    {
        xtable[i][j]=45;
    }
}
```

---

Since your class acquires resources using dynamic memory allocation, you should read up on [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and update your class accordingly.

Comment: and better yet, use `std::vector`

Comment: How can I ever thank you enough?! This did the trick. I've been studying possible solutions for over 12 hours now, but I've only come to understand now thanks to your response. Truly appreciate this; you are a lifesaver.

Comment: @KOne, glad I was able to help. As long as you learn from the experience, it's going to help you with your future programming efforts. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
int r,c;
cin>>r>>c;
int** p=new int*[r];
for(int i=0;i<r;i++) {
    p[i]=new int[c];
}
for(int i=0;i<r;i++) {
delete [] p[i]; 
}
delete [] p;
```

Using this code you can create a 2D Dynamic Array in C++ which would allocate the memory of this array in the Heap Memory.